# How to properly create and make a birthday field on a form submittable?

Tags: javascript, html, forms

I tried creating fields on a form for users to submit their birthday but the drop list for the month, date, and year never appeared. So I just had to enter the months and days into one drop menu for the form.

How do I create three fields for filling out birthday information on a form (Month,Date, Year) using html.

How do I make it show up when users submit their application using javascript?

```js
<script type='text/javascript'>
var form_script = {
form_id: $('#generic_form'),
status_id: $('#send_form'),
specific_id: $('#form_spec'),
enable_guests: false,
pm: {
enabled: false, // Does not work for guests
user: "", // 1 user only
title: "New acceptance test From {{user_name}}",
content: "{{form}}"
},
topic: {
enabled: true,
forum_id:3240482, // 1 id only
title: "About Me",
description: "Biography",
content: "{{form}}"
},
statuses: {
not_logged_in: "Error! You must be logged in to make an introduction topic.", // Used if enable_guests: false
first: "Verifying...",
second: "Processing...",
done: "Your introduction topic has been posted. You may customize your topic and edit the title."
},
submission_formatting: {
separator: ' ',

before_all: '',
after_all: '',

before_question: '[b]',
after_question: '[/b]',

before_response: '[i]',
after_response: '[/i]'
},
possible_elements: 'input, textarea, select' // For the second column of table; .val() must work on it
};
</script>
```

```html
<form id='generic_form'>
<div class='category'>
<table class='cat_head'>
<tr>
<td><h2 style='text-align:center'>Introduce Yourself</h2></td>
</tr>
</table>
</div>

<table>
<tr>
<td> </td>
</tr>
</table>

<table id='form_spec'>
<tr>
<th colspan='2'><h2>Please completely fill out all the requested information below with honesty:</h2></th>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Name:</td>
<td><input type='text' /></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Nickname:</td>
<td><input type='text' /></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Gender:</td>
<td>
<select>
<option>Male</option>
<option>Female</option>
<option>Unknown</option>
</select>
</td>
</tr>
<tr><td>Birthday:</td>
<td>
<select>
<option>N/A</option>
<option>January 1st</option>
<option>February 1st</option>
<option>March 1st</option>
<option>April 1st</option>
<option>May 1st</option>
<option>June 1st</option>   
<option>July 1st</option>
<option>August 1st</option>
<option>September 1st</option>
<option>October 1st</option>
<option>November 1st</option>
<option>December 1st</option>
</select>
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td colspan='2' id='send_form'><button type='submit'>Submit</button></td>
</tr>
</table>
</form>
```

Comment: Your question is not clear. What do you want to achieve exactly?

Comment: You have a syntax error in your code, which is probably why the two fields didn't show up correctly. To add extra dropdowns, you just need to create the relevant `<select>`s. Then you send these to JavaScript with `document.getElementById()`. Note that your `<input>`s will also need `name` attributes.

Answer (score 0):

The obvious idea is that you might have misunderstood the thing with setting up the selects by not using one for each part (day,month,year). Unless I have misunderstood what you are trying.

The HTML would be:

```
<select id="day" name="day">
  <option value="1">1</option>
  <option value="2">2</option>
  <option value="3">4</option>
  <option value="4">4</option>
  etc.. until 31.
</select>

<select id="month" name="month">
  <option value="January">January</option>
  <option value="February">February</option>
  etc.. until December
</select>

<select id="year" name="year">
  <option value="1940">1940</option>
  <option value="1941">1941</option>
  <option value="1942">1942</option>
  <option value="1943">1943</option>
  <option value="1944">1944</option>
  etc.. up til year 2017 (or what is max)
</select>
```

And javascript:

```
var day = document.getElementById('day').value ;
var month = document.getElementById('month').value ;
var year = document.getElementById('year').value ;
```

Some prefer months as numbers though and then you would do:

```
<select id="month" name="month">
  <option value="1">January</option>
  <option value="2>February</option>
  etc.. until December
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

I highly recommend using [jQuery Datepicker](https://jqueryui.com/datepicker/) in this instance. Reason being, there is an HTML answer to this question, unfortunately... not all browsers support it. That is the: `<input type="date">` parameter. If that worked globally, that would be the easiest thing to do.

Since it's not, it's a safe bet, especially for backwards compatibility, to still use JavaScript/jQuery. I like the jQuery Datepicker because of it's ease of use. Call in a few dependencies in your `<head>`

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
```

Execute this jQuery:

```
  <script>
  $( function() {
    $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker();
  });
  </script>
```

And add to your input field the id of "datepicker":

```
<input type="text" id="datepicker">
```

[LINK TO JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/tzhben/tb54j6ek/)

And there you have it. A very lightweight code that I think will produce the results you are after.

Comment: @Staywoke, any luck with trying any of the answers presented? If so, you should give credit to the person who gave the correct answer. Thanks!